# Android Studio: How to prevent up button in toolbar from pushing child view to the right?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

So I have a toolbar and it is the parent of a vertical linear layout containing two text views. When I run the activity without the up button everything looks fine. However, when I add the up button it appears to push the linear layout to the right. It seems like there's an implicit horizontal linear layout containing the up button and my own vertical linear layout.

If I cannot prevent the up button from doing this is there a way to set up the up button instead of doing it programmatically?

Sidenote: The reason I'm not using the ActionBar.SetTitle/SetSubtitle functions is because I can't style them how I want. However these functions don't have the same issue with the spacing.

Here's my activity code in my onCreate method. I've also added the relevant import statements:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

//Get tool bar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.thickToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        supportActionBar.hide();
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //If I comment out this line, things display normally. But ofc no up button
        final TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        final TextView actionBarSubtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_subtitle);
        supportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBarSubtitle.setText(query);
```

---

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.kreyoldict.kreyoldict.DefinitionActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarDefinitionActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/thickToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:theme="@style/AppActionBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Translated Word"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Original Text"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDefinitionActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="402dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewWordDefinition"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/tv_detail_activity_word_definition"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

<strike>Here's a picture of my 
[component tree][1]</strike> never mind, I need more rep to post 3+ links.

---

Here's a pic of the app with the up button and layout bounds:
[up button shenanigans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSAtB.png)

It's kinda hard to see because my toolbar is red, but it seems like the linear layout begins where the up button ends.

---

Here's a [picture with no up button and layout bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox2bh.png)

Comment: Toolbar is implicitly like a horizontal linear layout. If you enable the up button , all the content in the toolbar ll be placed to the right of the arrow button. Why don't you move the Linear Layout outside the toolbar ?

Comment: Because then it goes underneath the tool bar instead of on top. The parent of the tool bar is a linear layout.

Comment: You can hide the toolbar all together and create a Vertical Linear Layout .. with an ImageButton( Arrow ) and the Text Centered below it . Among many things you can use intent/fragment transaction on button click to go back !?

Comment: True, I've decided to keep the toolbar but replace the up button with an image button. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you add android:background="@android:color/transparent" in the ImageButton .. That way it won't take any extra padding space and ll make the image crisp!

Comment: For material design approach, I would recommend you to use CollapsingToolbarLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this attributes to toolbar  
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar               
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>
```

Comment: I already had the last three lines in my toolbar. I added the first two, but no dice, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to add navigation icon  in toolbar by image view..Use relative layout as root in toolbar and image view as top and your linear layout as center in parent.....working in my case.

Comment: Yeah that's the solution I came to earlier. Thanks though.